# Displaying rows with count 0 in MySQL using COUNT and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, count, outer-join

I have two tables, Subject and Content, where Content references Subject with foreign key. I want to display how many times each subject appears in Content table (0, if it does not appear). But the query below only gives me the rows with count > 0 and ignores the others:

```
SELECT Subject.id, Subject.name, COUNT(Content.subject_id) AS `count`
FROM Subject LEFT JOIN Content
ON Subject.id = Content.subject_id
WHERE type = @type
GROUP BY Subject.id;
```

I checked and tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855678/mysql-include-zero-rows-when-using-count-with-group-by), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478384/mysql-select-count-group-by-not-returning-rows-where-the-count-is-zero) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743456/displaying-rows-with-count-0-with-mysql-group-by) post but for some reason the code above does not work.

Any ideas?

Edit:
the type field is in the Content table and that was causing the the problem as "Will A" pointed out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which table is `type` a column in?  I'm supposing that it's Content - and by including the field in the WHERE clause, you're forcing the Content table on the right-hand side of the LEFT JOIN to have data in it (which means the LEFT JOIN is actually then just an INNER JOIN).

Try:

```
SELECT Subject.id, Subject.name, COUNT(Content.subject_id) AS `count`
FROM Subject
LEFT JOIN Content
ON Subject.id = Content.subject_id
AND type = @type
GROUP BY Subject.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Which table does column `type` belong to? If `type` is in `subject`, your left join should work. So I assume that `type` is in `Content`. Then the problem is that your WHERE clause won't match the cases where there are no matching lines in `Content`. Use

```
WHERE (type = @type) OR (type IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do an outer join instead. Replace the null with a 0. Replace non null with a 1. Instead of count, do a sum of this column.

Hope this helps

Comment: No, COUNT(something) skips null somethings. The error is in the `WHERE` vs the `JOIN`.